# Python, How to find the min and max of a variable used in programme , without using if statment.?

Tags: python

Let's say 'price' variable is used to record stock price during the day.
I need to know the min,max price during this period, without using comparison logic using if.
Is there a function for that in Python?
Thanks

Comment: If there were, what would you expect it to be named?

Comment: `max` and `min`.

Comment: Only one question: why?

Comment: How about "min" and "max"?

Comment: Do you mean https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.min.html and https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.max.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:
Create empty List pr
append new price every minute to list
When done , find min,max of List

pr=[]                 'create empty list
pr.append(price)      'add price every minute or so
min(pr),max(pr)       'get min,max of the list

This works, is there a shorter way?
Better to use List or array?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

min: numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.min.html
max: numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.max.html